# Cpanel hosted nodejs facebook webhook is verified but not working as per request

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cpanel, facebook-messenger

I created a private reply bot which replies all comments on my business page. My webhook is hosted to shared hosting(Cpanel) and its verified. but its not responding to any post requests from facebook. I tried it with heroku and its working fine there. what could be the reason??

I tried cpanel shell access too. but there's no console logs which I have on the app when it received the webhook requests. and there's no errors too. but facebook is sending the requests successfully. also I tried registering my app via application manager. but no results.

Also the stderr.log is not updating. it has the same error which I had ealier which I already corrected.

my files as below:

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const viewEngine = require("./src/config/viewEngine.js");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();

let app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//config view engine

viewEngine(app);

//initWebRoutes

//const User = require("./src/services/user.js");
const Receive = require("./src/services/receive.js");
const GraphApi = require("./src/services/graphApi.js");

const MY_VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.MY_VERIFY_TOKEN;

let users = {};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.render("homePage.ejs");
});
app.get("/privacy-policy", (req, res) => {
  return res.render("privacy-policy.ejs");
});

app.get("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = MY_VERIFY_TOKEN;

  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query["hub.mode"];
  let token = req.query["hub.verify_token"];
  let challenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];

  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {
    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === "subscribe" && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log("WEBHOOK_VERIFIED");
      res.status(200).send(challenge);
    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }
  }
});

app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  let body = req.body;

  /*console.log(`\u{1F7EA} Received webhook:`);
  console.dir(body, { depth: null });*/

  // Check if this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === "page") {
    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send("EVENT_RECEIVED");

    // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry &&
      body.entry.forEach(async function (entry) {
        if ("changes" in entry) {
          console.log(body);
          // Handle Page Changes event
          let receiveMessage = new Receive();
          if (entry.changes[0].field === "feed") {
            let change = entry.changes[0].value;
            let userName = change.from.name;
            switch (change.item) {
              case "post":
                return receiveMessage.handlePrivateReply(
                  "post_id",
                  change.post_id,
                  userName
                );
              case "comment":
                return receiveMessage.handlePrivateReply(
                  "comment_id",
                  change.comment_id,
                  userName
                );
              default:
                console.warn("Unsupported feed change type.");
                return;
            }
          }
        }
   });
    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});



app.listen();
```

.src/services/ graphApi.js:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require("url");
const axios = require("axios");
//const user = require("./user");

dotenv.config();

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PAGE_ID = process.env.PAGE_ID;
const VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.MY_VERIFY_TOKEN;
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;


module.exports = class GraphApi {
  static async callSendApi(requestBody) {
    // let url = new URL();

    /* url.search = new URLSearchParams({
      
    });*/
    console.warn("Request body is\n" + JSON.stringify(requestBody));

    let response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/${PAGE_ID}/messages`, {
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      params: { access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}` },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      consoleconst`Unable to call Send API: ${response.statusText}`,
        await response.json();
    }
  }

  static async callSubscriptionsAPI() {
    // Send the HTTP request to the Subscriptions Edge to configure your webhook
    // You can use the Graph API's /{app-id}/subscriptions edge to configure and
    // manage your app's Webhooks product
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge

    let url = new URL(`${API_URL}/${PAGE_ID}/subscribed_apps`, {
      params: {
        subscribed_feilds: `feed`,
        access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    let response = await axios.post(url, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(`Request sent.`);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Unable to callSubscriptionsAPI: ${response.statusText}`,
        await response.json()
      );
    }
  }
};
```

.src/services/recieve.js:

```
const GraphApi = require("./graphApi.js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
//const message = require("../message/message.json");
//const Response = require("./response.js");

dotenv.config();

module.exports = class Receive {
  /*constructor(user, webhookEvent, isUserRef) {
    this.user = user;
    this.webhookEvent = webhookEvent;
    this.isUserRef = isUserRef;
  }*/

  handlePrivateReply(type, object_id, userName) {
    let requestBody = {
      recipient: {
        [type]: object_id,
      },
      message: {
        text: ` Hi ${userName}!, welcome to Daisy Bloom . This is an automated reply to your comment made on our page. One of our team members will get back to you shortly.
          
      },
    };

    GraphApi.callSendApi(requestBody);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Page Events like Feed are only delivered to live apps (those that had been reviewed/approved).

You can use the Test functionality in your webhook config to send test events to your callback URL while in dev.

Comment: I'm receiving the webhook event of the comments posted via my profile as admin, while it was deployed to heroku. the problem is I'm not receiving that event once the app deployed in cpanel

Comment: I want to do the screen cast to get approved my app.